# What are the common issues that have arisen with Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa?

Tags: 20.04

In many different instances (and in my own instances), I have noticed bugs and problems with Focal Fossa. I have only had to deal with a few. As a developer, I would like to know most of the bugs, as I am working on an OS based off of Ubuntu 20.04, so that I can find them and neutralize them.

Comment: Then you might find [this reference](https://kifarunix.com/install-bugzilla-bug-tracker-on-ubuntu-20-04/) useful

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You might also find [this reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue671) of some help. Look at the "get Involved" section at the bottom.

Comment: Why not scan launchpad for bugs tagged on focal (20.04)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many bugs with sound. One, for example, is AlsaMixer detecting sound cards.